# How to select an 'Account' when adding Google Analytics to an app

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-sdk

> This is not specifically about programming but about setting up a GA
>   account to *finally start programming*. Also google himself redirected
>   me here and has closed their own google groups community. So I hope
>   you don't mind me bringing this up here:

I want to add Google Analytics to my iOS app.
So I'm going to
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/

I click on the "GET A CONFIGURATION FILE"-button, create an app and hit the Analytics-icon which shows me something like this:

[image: https://developers.google.com/mobile/add?blabla]

Now I have to select an account and a property. I have set up a few on https://analytics.google.com but the interface just doesn't allow me to choose the right one!

How can I select the right account for my app?

Bonus: Could anyone clarify the relationship between
https://developers.google.com/mobile/add
https://console.developers.google.com/project
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#management/Settings/
and the respective data models "app", "account" and "property" mentioned on the different sites?

Comment: To exclude the obvious, is at least one of your analytics properties configured for app tracking ? I would suspect that web-enabled properties cannot be selected.

Comment: Under "Property > Tracking Info > Tracking Code" it says "Mobile app tracking - Using the SDK" - so I guess, that's a yes.

Comment: Ok, I have found a solution for this: I trashed the Account that was stuck in the menu as shown above. Then everything worked as expected: Now It's giving me a nice dropdown to select the right account.

Comment: @de. thanks for your solution!

Comment: Ok - I finally found some documentation that sheds some light on the different data models: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009618?hl=en